# Where clause based on date from a label - Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, date, where-clause

How to convert a label for date into date format?

I have been trying to do that by using the below code and also convert it directly without a parse and trying another way that suggested from many sources, but it still give me an error:

```
Dim dateFrom As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lblDateFrom.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim dateTo As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(lblDateTo.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim sql2 As String = Nothing

sql2 = ";with cte as(select [Date], [Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason,  [Type] type, [Area] area, [Arm Band] ab, [Smock] item, [Smock Size] Size, [Smock Qty] Qty, [Smock Color] Color, row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Smock] order by getdate()) rn from tbl_Request2 where [Smock] Is Not null union select [DAte], [Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason,  [Type] type, [Area] area, [Arm Band] ab, [Shoes] item, [Shoes Size] Size, [Shoes Qty] Qty, [Shoes Color] Color,  row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Shoes] order by getdate()) rn from tbl_Request2 where [Shoes] is not null union select [Date], [Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason, [Type] type, [Area] area, [Arm Band] ab, [Safety Shoe] item, [SS Size] Size, [SS Qty] Qty, [SS Color] Color,  row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Safety Shoe] order by getdate()) rn from tbl_Request2 where [Safety Shoe] is not null union select [Date], [Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason, [Type] type, [Area] area, [Arm Band] ab, [Jumpsuit] item, [JP Size] Size, [JP Qty] Qty, [JP Color] Color,   row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Jumpsuit] order by getdate()) rn from tbl_Request2 where [Jumpsuit] is not null union select [Date], [Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason, [Type] type, [Area] area, [Arm Band] ab, [Booties] item, [Booties Size] Size, [Booties Qty] Qty, [Booties Color] Color, row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Booties] order by getdate()) rn from tbl_Request2 where [Booties] is not null union select [Date], [Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason, [Type] type, [Area] area, [Arm Band] ab, [Slipper] item, [Slipper Size] Size, [Slipper Qty] Qty, [Slipper Color] Color, row_number() over (partition by [Badge id], [Slipper] order by getdate()) rn from tbl_Request2 where [Slipper] is not null) insert into tbl_Approve ([DAte],[Badge id], Name, [Department], Reason, [Type], Area, [Arm Band], [Uniform], [Size],[Qty],[Color]) select [Date], [Badge id], Name, Department,  Reason, Type, Area, ab, item, Size, Qty,Color from cte where [date] between '" & Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom) & "' and '" & Convert.ToDateTime(dateTo) & "'"

Dim sql2cmd As New SqlCommand(sql2, con)
sql2cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The above code gives me an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

When I convert it directly using `System.Convert.ToDateTime(lbldatefrom.text)` in the SQL clause it give an error

> invalid date type........

Please.. can you help to solve this problem? I am using date type format in the database. 
the above code works well in the `varchar` type, but In this case I can't sort it base on date.

Thanks in advances... I really appreciate the thought...

Comment: You gotta learn to use **parametrized queries** - those are both safe against SQL injection, and using parameters, you can define what **type** these parameters are, and you can easily pass a .NET `DateTime` into a SQL query **without** any conversions that cost time and tend to fail at times.....

Comment: Thanks marc.... I Used parameter like you said... and it's work now... Thanks for the suggestion....